# WordPress plugin installation error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, installation, memory, fatal-error

I have installed WordPress 3.8 and now I am trying to install `WooCommerce - excelling eCommerce 2.0.20` plugin but every time I am getting this error:

**Note: I am trying to install plugin in local machine.**

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in M:\XAMPP\htdocs\woocommerce\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1327
```

I have tried with bellow code:

1. `php.ini` (in wp-admin folder)

   memory_limit = 32M
   upload_max_filesize = 100M
   upload_max_filesize = 100M
   post_max_size = 32M
   file_uploads = On
2. `wp-config.php`

   `set_time_limit(60);`

but still I am facing this error. I know this very common issue but I need your help to solve this issue.

I will appreciate If you help me :)

Thanks

Comment: Your install seem to hang performing HTTP request, it's impossible to guess why from info you have provided so far.

Comment: but what to do?

Comment: Ask hosting support or debug yourself or get someone to debug for you.

Comment: Are you running wordpress on local machine?

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes I am working on local.

Comment: @RahilWazir even jetpack is not installing.

Comment: Are you on a very slow connection? How long does it take for you to download the plugin zip file from WordPress.org with your browser?

Comment: @Otto 30 seconds or sometimes 1 minute

Comment: @Manan did you try my answer?

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes I am trying but still facing error :(

Comment: If it takes a minute to download a ZIP, and you have set_time_limit(60); in your file, then you're pushing that 60 second time limit awfully close. Maybe bump that up to 300 seconds instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but it occured while importing the theme-unit-test-data.xml along with its attachments. I am using WP 3.8.1. It's a WordPress issue so editing the php.ini has no effect. WP uses a hardcoded value (60 secs) for http_request_timeout of WP_Http in `class-http.php`.

To solve it, place this code in `functions.php` of your currently active theme:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', 'mytheme_bump_request_timeout', 100 );
function mytheme_bump_request_timeout(){
    return 300; //Change this to your desired timeout value in ms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `php.ini`

Should be located at `xampp/php/php.ini`

Find this line:

`max_execution_time`

Change its value to `300`

`max_execution_time = 300`

Here `300` means `5` minutes of execution time for the `http` request.

Comment: Yes I have changed  `max_execution_time=30` to `max_execution_time=300` but still I am getting error.

Comment: Have you made changes to `xampp/php/php.ini` file?

Comment: Yes file location is >`XAMPP/php/php.ini`

Comment: What execution time is being display in your `Fatal error` now?

Comment: Hi may be my net connection is slow after connecting with 3G, plugin is installed.